# Reference to a non-shared member Requires an object Referance - cant solve it

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Im getting a

> Reference to a non-shared member Requires an object Reference

error in this code:

```
Dim customersTableAdapter As Object
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    customersTableAdapter.Fill(DataBase.Table));
End Sub
```

this is my table code:

```
public System.Data.DataSet Table{
    get { return table; }
    set { table = value; }
}
```

ive tried putting this in:

```
Dim DB As new DataBase
```

but just cant get it working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`.Table` is not static/shared property of type `DataBase`.
Not static properties must be accessed through instance of the type
You already created a instance of the type `DataBase`

```
Dim DB As new DataBase
```

Use this instance to access `DB.Table` property

```
Dim customersTableAdapter As Object
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    customersTableAdapter.Fill(DB.Table));
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here.

Looking at this line:

```
Dim DB As new DataBase
```

Am I to assume that the `Table` property is on the `DataBase` object?  In that case, what you're doing here is incorrect:

```
customersTableAdapter.Fill(DataBase.Table))
```

You're trying to call `Table` on the `DataBase` class itself, not on an actual instance of that class.  You need an instantiated object in order to use a property on that object.  So instantiate one:

```
Dim DB As new DataBase
```

And use that object:

```
customersTableAdapter.Fill(DB.Table))
```

---

Additionally, this isn't going to work:

```
Dim customersTableAdapter As Object
' ...
customersTableAdapter.Fill(DB.Table))
```

Because `Object` has no method called `Fill`.  You *probably* want to use something more specific than `Object`.

---

You're also seriously mixing VB and C# here, which isn't going to work *at all*.  Separate projects (or at least separately compiled units) can be different languages.  But trying to use both languages *in the same code* is going to result in lots of syntax errors and un-compilable code.